# Matlab Coordinate system?

Tags: matlab

How to assign a new coordinate system different than the global coordinates (x,y)

for example, i need the new coordinate system to be a sine wave i drew on Matlab, is there a function or a way to draw another sine function on the initial one?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Are you asking how to graph two functions on the same axes?  Because that is very different that a new coordinate system.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to draw multiple plots in one axes, use `hold`:

```
x = linspace(0,4*pi);
figure; plot(x, sin(x));
hold on;
plot(x, sin(2*x));
hold off;
```

As soon as you state `hold on`, all calls to `plot()` will draw in the same figure until you call `hold off`.
If you'd like to have several axes in one figure, use `subplot()`:

```
x = linspace(0,4*pi);
figure; % open new figure window
subplot(2, 1, 1); % 2 lines of subplots, one column, use first one
plot(x, sin(x));
subplot(2, 1, 2); % ... use second one
plot(x, sin(2*x));
```

If you'd like to have several figure windows, open a new figure for each plot with `figure`:

```
x = linspace(0,4*pi);
figure; % open figure window for first plot
plot(x, sin(x));
figure; % open new figure window for second plot
plot(x, sin(2*x));
```

Note, that in the above example `plot()` always uses the figure window that has been created last. You can also use figure handles to draw into the figure windows arbitrarily:

```
x = linspace(0,4*pi);
figure; % open figure window for first plot
fig1 = gca; % get current axes handle
figure; % open new figure window for second plot
fig2 = gca;
plot(fig2, x, sin(x)); % draw into second figure window
plot(fig1, x, sin(2*x)); % draw into first figure window
```